# Editor-xtd custom button with external Iframe Call

Tags: plugin

I am developing a custom button to integrate with an external commercial publishing software. My button base works and some how the iframe is called onto my test web site where the external App and Joomla are both installed.

To be specific my button has a link, which is fired in an iFrame:

```
$link = 'http://somehost.com/application_dir/widgets/selection?';

$button = new JObject();
$button->set('modal', true);
$button->set('class', 'btn');
$button->set('link', $link);
$button->set('text', JText::_('PLG_CANDAMFOTOWEB8_SIGEBUTTONTEXT'));
$button->set('name', 'wand');

$button->set('options', "{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 600, y: ".$height_modal."}}");
$button->onclick = 'CandamFW8BtnClick(\''.$name.'\'); return false;';
```

My issue here is that in the back-end, joomla Editor adds the `JURI::base()` to the link, so that the iframe address becomes:

> http://localhost/joomla/administrator/http://somehost.com/application_dir/widgets/selection?

Is there an easy way to override the href generated once the button is displayed (an `afterDisplay` event may be) right this code sits in the `onDisplay()` event...

I thought of using a php proxy which in turn would call an external iframe, but it does not help, since `JURI::base(` still returns the `site/administrator` path and my php proxy has to sit in the `site/plugins/pluginname/` directory.

Any idea what could work?

Answer (score 2):

I finally gave up on this method and replaced the $link on the Joomla custom editor Button with an empty reference "#", and managed the iframe display outside in the Javascript code attached to the $button->onclick event.

By using a Bootstrap popup window in which I load the external Iframe, i solved the issue. This just required to change the approach to the issue. By loading the external Iframe in the Javascript i am free from the Joomla Framework default base reference introduced in the Editor button links.