# How to make my Editor plugin (type: editors-xtd) survive after updates?

Tags: plugin, editor, joomla-3.9

I have a project that I am writing a component, module, and editor plugin for.

I have managed to piece together a rudimentary plugin that works with TinyMCE (at least) which:

1. Displays a custom button
2. Triggers a popup modal window containing a dynamic table of buttons using db data
3. Inserts a custom, curly-braced placeholder into an article.

The part that I am concerned with is making my solution "upgrade proof".

I followed https://mrgott.com/13-joomla/17-how-to-create-joomla-editors-xtd-plugin-button-and-open-modal-popup as much as I could, until I needed to break away and build beyond what is mentioned.  That resource warns:

> NOTE: Yes, the first question that arises is: What if after each
>   update your file will be removed as it’s not a part of Joomla’s
>   com_content component. Yeah, that’s right, but actually I’m fine by
>   keeping this file, and uploading it after each system update, rather
>   then doing plugin development in the wrong and dirty way.
>
> If you are building this plugin for your client, you should better
>   build a component, or maybe you already built some component and just
>   add a new view file there for your editors-xtd plugin.

I feel like my component will need more than just a new file in `views`. I would rather learn "the right way".  I don't want to ["give up" like Philippe](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/13861/12352). What files do I need to create (copy into my component and modify) to make my plugin long-lasting?  I could also use a tip on how to add a little icon to my custom button in the editor; right now I only have text with an empty space on its left side.

The `onDisplay()` function in `/plugins/editors-xtd/picturelinkcode/picturelinkcode.php`:

```
public function onDisplay($name)
{       
    $query_string = [
        "option" => "com_content",      // I want this to be "com_picture",
        "view"   => "article",
        "layout" => "picturelinkcode",  // some examples use "modal" here
        "tmpl"   => "component",
        "editor" => $name
    ];

    $link = 'index.php?' . http_build_query($query_string);

    $button = new JObject;
    $button->modal = true;
    $button->class = 'btn';
    $button->link  = $link;
    $button->text  = JText::_('Linkcode');
    $button->name  = 'picturelinkcode';
    $button->options = "{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 600, y: 400}}";

    return $button;
}
```

The `/administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/picturelinkcode.php` file:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$document     = JFactory::getDocument();
$this->editor = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('editor', '');
$this->editor = preg_replace('~[^\w[\]-]+~', '', $this->editor);  // sanitize

/**
 * ...better coding practice would probably be
 * to store the js and the data processing
 * outside of this tmpl file
 *   --apologies while sprinting
 */
$script  = 'function insertPictureLinkcode(linkcode) {' . "\n";
$script .= '  var tag = "{loadpicture " + linkcode + "}";' . "\n";
$script .= '  window.parent.jInsertEditorText(tag, ' . json_encode($this->editor) . ');' . "\n"; // "jform_articletext"
$script .= '  window.parent.jModalClose();' . "\n";
$script .= '  return false;' . "\n";
$script .= '}' . "\n";

JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration($script);

?><h3>Picture Linkcodes</h3><?php

// Retrieve all linkcodes and their associated counts
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$subquery = $db->getQuery(true)
               ->select("id")
               ->from("#__fields")
               ->where([
                   "context = 'com_picture.picture'",
                   "name = 'linkcode'"
                 ]);
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select("value AS linkcode, COUNT(*) AS picturecount")
            ->from("#__fields_values")
            ->where("field_id = ($subquery)")
            ->group("value");
$db->setQuery($query);

try
{
    $resultset = $db->loadObjectList();
    if (!$resultset)
    {
        echo "No Linkcodes Available Yet<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <form class="form">
            <table>
                <?php
                foreach ($resultset as $row)
                {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="insertPictureLinkcode('<?php echo $row->linkcode; ?>');" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <?php echo $row->linkcode; ?>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            (<?php echo $row->picturecount; ?>)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<div class='bg-danger'>Picture Linkcode Query Error - Contact Developer</div>";
    //echo "<div class='bg-danger'>" , $query->dump() , "<br>" , $e->getMessage() , "</div>";
}
```

Screenshots of my currently functional coding attempt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OabHq.jpg (I should ask @Eoin what tech he uses to make [those nifty animated gifs](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23828/12352))

In case it matters, my component is nearly identical to the core's `adminstistrator/components/com_contact` and my module will only have one job -- to replace placeholders in articles with dynamic content.  My plugin will eventually have greater functionality than I am showing in this question.

Comment: The button should link to the item list view of your component. In `com_contact` this would be the `contacts` view. Does your component have a model-view where items are retrieved using the database queries shown in your question?

Comment: My `com_picture` doesn't yet have any altered files.  All of the folders and files are just like `com_contact` with the exception that I have altered filenames, variable names, class names, and maybe a function name or two to align with `picture` instead of `contact`.  If I can get away with not writing a `mod_picture` module to render my `{placeholder}` that would be best.  Have I answered your question properly? @Sharky

Comment: I blindly attempted to copy my working `picturelinkcode.php` file from `/administrator/components/com_content/view/article/tmpl` to `/administrator/components/com_picture/view/article/tmpl` but that resulted in **View not found [name, type, prefix]: article, html, pictureView**  I only understand about 45% of what I am doing, the rest is "Joomla magic" to me.  I don't fully understand the data that I am using in `$query_string`.  ...Ah, I have not yet created an `index.html` and `view.html.php` files in `com_picture/views/article/tmpl`

Comment: Should I be using a `modal.php` file  in my `article/tmpl` folder instead of calling the file `picturelinkcode.php`?  More intuitive I think.

Comment: I'm still unsure of how and where you're planning to store your items. If you renamed everything from `contact` to `picture`, you probably have `#__picture_details` table in your database. But you're querying `#__fields_values` table instead? So, are your items just custom field values or do you intend to manage them like in other components (e.g. `com_contact`) and store them in their own table?

Comment: I do have a `#__picture_details` table generated which contains the basic/identifying info on pictures (`name`, `alias`, `published`; otherwise the Edit Picture interface has been mostly gutted). The component will be relying largely on the `#__fields_values` table for lots of new custom fields data that will be controlled and generated by our client. I am very likely to be making several mistakes in this process.  Both tables will be in play depending on the process.

Comment: I guess you could say the two item types are unrelated. In which case you should make a separate model/view for the items from fields table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the plugin would open a list of items. In this case, the component doesn't have the model/view for the items. So you have to create them.

As a bare minimum, the model must contain `getListQuery()` method which returns the query used to retrieve the items.

administrator/components/com_picture/models/items.php:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class PictureModelItems extends JModelList
{
    protected function getListQuery()
    {
        // Retrieve all linkcodes and their associated counts
        $db = $this->_db;
        $subQuery = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->quoteName('id'))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__fields'))
            ->where(
                [
                    $db->quoteName('context') . ' = ' . $db->quote('com_picture.picture'),
                    $db->quoteName('name') . ' = ' . $db->quote('linkcode'),
                ]
            );

        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select([$db->quoteName('value', 'linkcode'), 'COUNT(*) AS picturecount'])
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__fields_values'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('field_id') . ' = (' . $subQuery . ')')
            ->group($db->quoteName('value'));

        return $query;
    }
}
```

The view, as a bare minimum, must retrieve the items.

administrator/components/com_picture/views/items/view.html.php:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class PictureViewItems extends JViewLegacy
{
    protected $items;

    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $this->items = $this->get('Items');

        return parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

Then, in the view layout output the list of items in a table or whatever other format you prefer.

In the button plugin, change `link` property to point to your new view:

```
$button->link = 'index.php?option=com_picture&amp;view=items&amp;layout=modal&amp;tmpl=component&amp;editor=' . $name . '&amp;' . JSession::getFormToken() . '=1';
```

> I could also use a tip on how to add a little icon to my custom button in the editor

The icon is coming from button's `name` property. It gets `icon-` added in front to form a IcoMoon icon class. E.g. if you set it to `joomla` the resulting class will be `icon-joomla`. See all icons [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Joomla_Standard_Icomoon_Fonts).

Comment: I've had to continue sprinting with this project, but I do intend to circle back and try your advice.  Could you please specify where these new files need to be located?  And can you explain why your solution (and several others that I have seen) are using `&amp;` in `$button->link` while my original script works fine with just `&`?

Comment: Updated the answer to indicate file locations.

Comment: My guess is ampersand is escaped for compatibility with older browsers/templates and HTML validity.

Comment: Okay @Sharky I have `com_picture/models/items.php` returning the successful query. The `var_dump($this->items)` is delivering the expected result set.  I am calling `$this->items` from inside of `com_picture/views/items/tmpl/modal.php` and writing all my dom there.  This is what your are advising me to do, right?

Comment: I need to include some js and css into my modal (specifically: `media/com_picture/js/admin-article-o3_insertpicturestag.js` and `media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css` Can you recommend the appropriate syntax?  Is this the best line for the js? `JHtml::script(Juri::root() . 'media/com_picture/js/admin-article-o3_insertpicturestag.js');`  I don't have a working Joomla-style css inclusion, I am hacking with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous">
`

Comment: I tried a heap of things like: `JHtmlBootstrap::framework(true);` and `$doc->addStyleSheet(JPATH_ROOT . '/css/bootstrap_3.css');` and `$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root() . 'media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'text/css');` and `$document->addStyleSheet(str_replace("/administrator", "", $this->baseurl) . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'text/css');` but even if I get the path right, the library isn't accessed and bootstrap css is not applied to my elements.  I'm hoping you can share the most appropriate way to load bootstrap for the modal.

Comment: You can use `relative` flag and omit `media` and `js` folders, these will be auto-detected: `JHtml::_('script', 'com_picture/admin-article-o3_insertpicturestag.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));`. Otherwise add them too `JHtml::_('script', 'media/com_picture/js/admin-article-o3_insertpicturestag.js', array('version' => 'auto'));`. Is your template based on Bootstrap? If it is, I suspect that you're not loading the CSS in template's `component.php` file but you should. I've seen too many templates that generate unstyled pages when using `tmpl=component` query.

Comment: As for the .js inclusion, I just checked my commented-out attempts.  `JHtml::_('script', 'com_picture/js/admin-article-o3_insertpicturestag.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));` is what I first tried before my JHTML::script(Juri::root()...` work around.  I tried it again and it says that my function in the file is not defined (the resource isn't loaded).  What might be the issue?  I've told you the filepaths.  Everything is in the right location isn't it?

Comment: As for the styling, I am going to passing my work to someone else who will be doing all of the styling.  I am pretty sure that he is going to use CSS Grid, but I am trying to draft things with bootstrap to get the general concept in place.  Are you saying I should abstract my component further to include a full-blown template? (it seems like overkill to me, but maybe it is not)

Comment: For the first one remove `js` folder because you are using `relative` flag. For the second one I can only guess it's the same. Note that you don't need to use `JUri::root()` here.

Comment: removing `/js` gives me `undefined` with the resource not loading.  AAAHHH, there is something wrong with `if (!window.parent.Joomla.getOptions('xtd...` in my .js file. What should `...` be?

Comment: I previously copied `if (!Joomla.getOptions('xtd-contacts')) {
   // Something went wrong!
   window.parent.jModalClose();
   return false;
  }` from `media/com_contact/js/admin-contacts-modal.js` to create my `admin-article-o3_insertpicturestag.js`  I removed the conditional checkpoint and everything works, but do I need to keep this checkpoint to be safe?

Comment: I am not able to load the preloaded `jui/css/bootstrap.min.css` resource with `JHtml::_'script'..` approach.  I merely need to apply the existing copy of bootstrap to render my modal properly.

Comment: That snippet is related to this code in `modal.php` layout: `JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptOptions('xtd-contacts', array('editor' => $editor));`. Change `xtd-contacts` in both places to something else, e.g. `xtd-pictures`. Regarding Bootstrap, it is still unclear whether your template includes BS styling globally (in `index.php` file) or not. If it does, it should also do so in `component.php` file.

Comment: To load Joomla's Bootstrap files, use `JHtml::_('bootstrap.loadCss', true, $direction);` where `$direction` is language direction. To load specific stylesheets: `JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'jui/bootstrap.min.css', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));` or `JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css', array('version' => 'auto'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89230/discussion-between-mickmackusa-and-sharky).