# Add a custom layout for editor-xtd popup

Tags: editor

Another [post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/how-to-make-my-editor-plugin-type-editors-xtd-survive-after-updates?noredirect=1&lq=1) partially answered my question, but I want to know if and how would be possible to make use of `addLayoutPath` and `setLayout` in my `editor-xtd` plugin. Here's my plugin so far

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class PlgButtonVimeo extends JPlugin
{

    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    public function onDisplay($name)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $input = $app->input;
        $user  = JFactory::getUser();

        // Can create in any category (component permission) or at least in one category
        $canCreateRecords = $user->authorise('core.create', 'com_content')
            || count($user->getAuthorisedCategories('com_content', 'core.create')) > 0;

        // Instead of checking edit on all records, we can use **same** check as the form editing view
        $values = (array) $app->getUserState('com_content.edit.article.id');
        $isEditingRecords = count($values);

        // This ACL check is probably a double-check (form view already performed checks)
        $hasAccess = $canCreateRecords || $isEditingRecords;
        if (!$hasAccess)
        {
            return;
        }

        // I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SET THIS CODE HERE
        // $this IS OUT OF CONTEXT
        // $root = $app->isSite() ? '' : '../';
        // $this->addLayoutPath($root.'plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/tpl');
        // $this->setLayout('vimeo');

        JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptOptions('xtd-vimeo', array('editor' => $name));
        $link = 'index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;layout=vimeo&amp;tmpl=component&amp;e_name=' . $name;

        $button          = new JObject;
        $button->modal   = true;
        $button->class   = 'btn';
        $button->link    = $link;
        $button->text    = JText::_('PLG_EDITORSXTD_VIMEO_BUTTON');
        $button->name    = 'palette';
        $button->options = "{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}";

        return $button;
    }
}
```

The view at `vimeo.php` is just a copy-paste of the pagebreak view in `administrator/components/con_content/views/article/tmpl/pagebreak.php` for now, it will be edited accordingly:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::_('behavior.core');
JHtml::_('behavior.polyfill', array('event'), 'lt IE 9');
JHtml::_('script', 'com_content/admin-article-pagebreak.min.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));

$document    = JFactory::getDocument();
$this->eName = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('e_name', '');
$this->eName = preg_replace('#[^A-Z0-9\-\_\[\]]#i', '', $this->eName);

$document->setTitle(JText::_('COM_CONTENT_PAGEBREAK_DOC_TITLE'));
?>
<div class="container-popup">
    <form class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="title" class="control-label"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_PAGEBREAK_TITLE'); ?></label>
            <div class="controls"><input type="text" id="title" name="title" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="alias" class="control-label"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_PAGEBREAK_TOC'); ?></label>
            <div class="controls"><input type="text" id="alt" name="alt" /></div>
        </div>

        <button onclick="insertPagebreak('<?php echo $this->eName; ?>');" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_PAGEBREAK_INSERT_BUTTON'); ?>
        </button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: As an aside, I'll chime in to say that your pattern should be refined to `#[^\w[\]-]+#` because `\w` = `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, `-` doesn't need to be escaped if it is at the beginning or end of the character class or if it immediately follows a range of characters (such as `\w`), the opening square brace does not require escaping because you cannot start a new character class from inside a character class, and the closing brace needs to remain escaped so that it does not prematurely close the character class.  Test your patterns and learn what they ate doing at https://regex101.com

Comment: Oh, and the plus sign is to match 1 or more consecutive characters in the chatacter class.  This is a matter of efficiency.  If I put a carton of 12 eggs at your feet and told you to pick up a dozen eggs ... it would be inefficient to perform 12 squads picking 1 egg at a time -- just pick up all 12 on the first squat.  The Joomla core code fails to realize/apply this simple logic. (I am usually disappointed with the regex patterns within)

Comment: Ha, I just realized that you linked to my question and my recommended pattern was already there.

Comment: Thanks for joining the struggle! I was reading about [JLayout](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout) but it seems to be something for front-end. I just need something similar but appropriate  for my need. Also yours hopefully.

Comment: Really hope to find a solution bcz I don't wanna `revive` stuff on every update :)

Comment: Hey have you tried [this](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=711470#p3035882)? Looks a bit wacky but worth a try.

Comment: Apparently, you can use `com_ajax` with editor buttons. But the plugin class name has to use `EditorsXtd` group instead of `Button` (which is used in core plugins). I didn't know this when answering the linked question (sorry @mickmackusa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `com_ajax`:

Rename `PlgButtonVimeo` class to `PlgEditorsXtdVimeo`.

Point button link to `com_ajax`:

```
$link = 'index.php?option=com_ajax&amp;plugin=vimeo&amp;group=editors-xtd&amp;format=html&amp;tmpl=component&amp;'
    . JSession::getFormToken() . '=1&amp;e_name=' . $name;
```

Add `onAjaxVimeo` method:

```
public function onAjaxVimeo()
{
    // Renders plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/tmpl/default.php.
    ob_start();
    include JPluginHelper::getLayoutPath($this->_type, $this->_name);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa you can try this to make your editor-xtd button immortal. I tested and it's working fantastic.

Comment: @thednp sometimes Sharky's answers need a little touching up.  I am going to vote to approve your suggested edit,  but in most scenarios you should not modify the code in an answer (often it is better to notify the poster and give them the chance to update it themselves or defend why they have written what they have written).

Comment: @mickmackusa I implemented the solution into my code and noticed I didn't get the form name into the view. I specifically mentioned the code used was from `pagebreak.php` view, so I was expecting to be a value for `e_name`, but I will keep in mind in the future.

Comment: Sadly this won't work with Joomla 4. With all the namespace updates I did and researched so far.

Comment: UPDATE: the updated code that supposed to work on J4, works fine on J3.9.5.

Comment: Update: after further investigation, the `com_ajax` actually works, the problem relies with `<fieldset addfieldpath="/plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/models/fields">`, but I will open a new issue for that.