# Joomla 4 - how to set namespace for custom field addfieldprefix

Tags: custom-field, joomla-4.x

I have the `editors-xtd\vimeo` plugin with this structure

```
..\plugins\editors-xtd\vimeo\models\fields\(a bunch of custom fields)
..\plugins\editors-xtd\vimeo\forms\form.xml
..\plugins\editors-xtd\vimeo\forms\extra.xml
```

In both the `.xml` files I used

`<fieldset addfieldpath="/plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/models/fields">`

All working perfect in Joomla 3.9.5+ but I don't know how to set the `addfieldprefix` in Joomla 4, already tried (according to the [JAB presentation](https://joomla.digital-peak.com/images/blog/JAB17%20Prepare%20you%20extension%20for%20Joomla%204.pdf)) to

```
<fieldset name="vimeo-options" addfieldprefix="Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo">
```

In a [previous question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24567/add-a-custom-layout-for-editor-xtd-popup), I found out how to use `com_ajax` to set a custom layout for the plugin, here is how I load the `.xml` files in my layout

```
..\plugins\editors-xtd\vimeo\tmpl\default.php
```

via

```
Form::addFormPath(JPATH_ROOT.'/plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/forms/');
$form = Form::getInstance('form',JPATH_ROOT.'/plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/forms/form.xml');
$form->addFieldPath(JPATH_ROOT.'/plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/models/fields/');
$form->loadFile('extra',false,false);
```

The pop-up content is empty, no fields loaded from `extra.xml`.

Thanks for any input/suggestion.

Comment: Above you define the Form like this: `$form = Form::getInstance('form',JPATH_ROOT.'/plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/forms/form.xml');` but you want to load `extra.xml`, then the path is not correct.

Comment: I also do not think that you need to use field prefix. The fieldset should be like: `<fieldset name="vimeo-options" label="PLG_SOMETHING_SOMETHING" addfieldpath="plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/models/fields">` - these two things I can see suddenly...

Comment: Neither `addfieldpath="something"` or `addfieldprefix="something"` works.

Comment: Update: the form is loaded with `$form->addFieldPath(JPATH_ROOT.'/plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/models/fields/');` and removed `addfieldpath` attribute for the fieldsets in the `.xml` files, but I didn't actually see anything until I inspected the source. The form is there, just for some reason getting a value of some field via `$form->getField('fieldName')` breaks everything.

Comment: I mean a `var_dump($form)` right after loading the `.xml` files gets the form into the page.

Comment: Your plugin is not namespaced. `addfieldprefix()` is for namespaced extensions only.

Comment: It's not only that @Sharky, I enabled `show_errors` in `php.ini` and I will post a new question, hopefully solve this issue today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement Joomla standard namespacing in a plugin, follow these steps:

First, declare extension's namespace in manifest file:

```
<namespace>Joomla\Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo</namespace>
```

If you are editing files on site, you need to delete `libraries/autoload_ps4.php` file so it can regenerated. If you update the plugin using extension manager, this should be done automatically.

Fields must be placed in plugin's `Field` directory. So move the contents of
 `plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/models/fields` to `plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/Field`.

Field classes and filenames consist of field type and `Field` suffix. Field type must start with an uppercase and is case sensitive. The filename would be `plugins/editors-xtd/vimeo/Field/ExampleField.php` and the class name `ExampleField`. `$type` property should not contain suffix. You must also add namespace delcaration. An example of field looks like this:

```
namespace Joomla\Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo\Field;

defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Form\Field\ListField;

class ExampleField extends ListField
{
    protected $type = 'Example';
}
```

To register fields use `addfieldprefix="Joomla\Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo\Field` in form.

In form field type should not have a suffix:

```
<field
    name="whatever"
    type="Example"
/>
```

If you use camelcase for files/classes, the type in form must be case correctly, e.g. if filename is `MyExampleField`, the type in form should be `MyExample` because `Myexample` or `myexample` will not be detected.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry to bother you. What about the plugin class declaration itself please? `EditorsXtdVimeoPlugin extends CMSPlugin` is that correct?

Comment: Plugin class should remain as `PlgEditorsXtdVimeo` for now.

Comment: Omg this really worked, thank you so much,

Comment: Where is the `libraries/autoload_ps4.php` file in Joomla 3.9.6 please?

Comment: It's only in 4.0.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work properly in Joomla 3.9.6. And with Joomla 4 the namespaced fields only work with their plugin, cannot get accessed elsewhere like a template or another plugin.

Comment: Yes, this does not work in 3.9. It _might_ work in 3.10 if related code is backported from 4.0 (3.10 should receive some 4.0 compatibility features). Otherwise in 3.x you need another plugin for registering the namespace using `JLoader::registerNamespace()`.

Comment: That changed in RC version of Joomla! 4. Autoloader cache file is in /administrator/cache now