# Access namespaced custom field method from a plugin into another plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field, php7, joomla-4.x

In [one of my previous questions](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24685/joomla-4-how-to-set-namespace-for-custom-field-addfieldprefix/24691), I learned how to properly set up a namespaced custom form field, but it turns out that it's only available within its plugin scope for some reason.

I need the field defined in `plugins/editorsxtd/vimeo/Field/VimeoOptionsField.php` to use its class in `plugins/content/vimeo/vimeo.php` -- also a namespaced extension now.

```
// namespace Joomla\Plugin\Content;

defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;
use Joomla\Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo\Field\VimeoOptionsField;

class PlgContentVimeo extends CMSPlugin
{
  protected $autoloadLanguage = true;
  public static $options = array();

  function __construct(&$a, $b)
  {
    if(empty(static::$options))
    {
      // returns an array with options
      static::$options = Joomla\Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo\Field\VimeoOptionsField::getOptionsList();
    }
  }
  public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0){
    // do the magic with static::$options
  }
}
```

This setup throws this error:

> Class 'Joomla\Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo\Field\VimeoOptionsField' not found
>   site\plugins\content\vimeo\vimeo.php:31

---

**UPDATE 1:**

The `use Joomla\Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo\Field\VimeoOptionsField;` declaration doesn't load the class into my plugin. I also tried  JLoader:

```
JLoader::registerNamespace('Joomla\Plugin\EditorsXtd\Vimeo\Field\VimeoOptionsField', JPATH_PLUGINS.'/editors-xtd/vimeo/Field/VimeoOptionsField.php');
```

But this is not working either.

Question:

Does `JLoader::('NAMESPACE','PATH_TO_FIELD')` need anything else? or what exactly do I need to call to access the methods in the `plugins/content/vimeo/vimeo.php` class shown here?

**UPDATE 2:**
After a close inspection, comparing code from Joomla 3.9 and Joomla 4, I came to the realization that Joomla 3.9. still uses old `JFormFieldFieldname` class, no namespace so that explains why it's not working in Joomla 3, not yet, perhaps with v3.9.10.

Comment: Which version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: I want to make extensions to work with both Joomla versions. I have to make use of something like `!class_exists -> New_class extend OLD_Class`.

Comment: Just FYI: on Joomla 4 it works, but only inside the plugin scope, not outside, in something like another plugin or template. I would like to know how to make that work at least so I can prepare my extensions roadmap accordingly.

Comment: I will post another question regarding reusing these namespaced custom form fields in other plugins or extensions.