# No Documentation about onCustomEditorButton

Tags: plugin, editor, tinymce

I want to add a custom button to the TinyMCE editor. But the documentation about this feature is non-existsten as you can see here: https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Editor#onCustomEditorButton

Do you have any idea how this works or other sources of a useful documentation?

Comment: What button do you intend to include?  Maybe start reading https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23899/12352 then check out the linked / related pages on the side panel.

Answer (score 2):

What you've currently link to in your question is a plugin event for a custom editor button, not for the actual creation of one.

To create a custom button, check the following directory:

> ROOT/plugins/editors-xtd/

where you will see a few core extension.

You can copy any of these and start writing your code inside the `onDisplay()` function